# How to loop through an object in smarty

Tags: php, object, smarty

I have a script which is passing an object array to smarty like so:

```
$smarty->assign('results', $user->results());
```

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [agency_name] => Agency #1
        [created_date] => 2015-03-25 20:23:44
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [agency_name] => gggg
        [created_date] => 2015-03-25 21:26:06
    )

)
```

How can I loop through this object array using smarty?  I have tried something like this, with no luck..

```
{section name="i" loop=$result}
{$result[i]->id}
{/section}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using smarty assign_by_ref

```
$smarty->assign_by_ref('object', $object)
```

Answer (score 2):

// In smarty you can loop through your array like this:

```
{foreach from=$results item=result}
{$result->id}
{/foreach}
```

// You can also use "key=xx" and a "{foreachelse}" before the end of the loop in case there's nothing inside the array.

Comment: Yes I know I can do a foreach on a standard array but what about on an object array? I tried the above code but it doesn't work.

Comment: try using {foreach from=$results key=i item=result} {$result[i]->id}{/foreach}

Comment: Same result. Maybe I have to assign the object differently in smarty?

Comment: The first example should work if you use it as it is without the [i] key. The stdClass should be well understood by Smarty and it just converts it to an Array as it originally is an array. What error are you getting

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just no output yet I can see it is looping over the rows twice and there are two rows which is why I can't work it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73817/discussion-between-keithm-and-v4n1ll4).